# How to correctly link OpenCV release and debug libraries in cmake with visual studio generator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, unresolved-external

I have a project (minimal reproducable example can be found [here](https://github.com/IjonTichiy/opencvLinkerTest)) which i am building with cmake and use "Visual Studio 17 2022" generator. In this project i include OpenCV *.lib and *.dll files so that users of this project don't have to compile/install OpenCV themeselves.
I want to be able to build this project in release and debug modes.
Since i am using Visual Studio as my generator, which is a multi configuration generator, i do not want to use the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` since it shouldn't do anything for these types of generators (please correct me if i am wrong here). So instead of using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` i use the variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` which is set in my toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` to `"Release;Debug"`.

When i configure the project with cmake i use this line:

```
cmake.exe -S . -B build -A x64
```

now when i build this project in Release mode everything works fine. I build it using this command:

```
cmake.exe --build build --config Release --target install
```

The trouble begins when i want to build the project in debug mode:

```
cmake.exe --build build --config Debug --target install
```

which produces the following error message

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@@Z) referenced in function main
[D:\Projekte\OpenCVLinkerTest\build\apps\app1\app1.vcxproj]
D:\Projekte\OpenCVLinkerTest\build\apps\app1\bin\Debug\app1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [D:\Projekte\OpenCVLinkerTest\build\apps\app1\a
pp1.vcxproj]
```

note the specific class `cv::debug_build_guard` which is unresolved. My guess at the moment is that i can not link OpenCV release libraries with my debug build.
So therefore i included OpenCV debug libraries in the lib folder in the repo i linked above.
now i have two folders in lib:
`lib/opencv/debug` and `lib/opencv/release` which both have `OpenCVConfig.cmake` files in them.

What i do not understand is how do i correctly pick the right library within my `CMakeLists.txt`. Currently i do this:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
    PATHS 
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/opencv/release"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/opencv/debug"
)
```

which just finds the release OpenCVConfig.cmake file i guess and ignores the debug files.

So, how do i do this correctly? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: How are you linking OpenCV to your target? Can you share some more of your `CMakeLists`?

Comment: @AndréLehto the complete cmakelists.txt can be found in the repo i linked. Here is the link to the toplevel file https://github.com/IjonTichiy/opencvLinkerTest/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
and here the lower level one which links to opencv https://github.com/IjonTichiy/opencvLinkerTest/blob/master/apps/app1/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Where did you get your OpenCV source code?

Comment: @AndréLehto https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.7.0 this is the source i used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since i had the following cmake files in the debug and release subdirectories:

```
|lib/opencv/release
||OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
||OpenCVConfig.cmake
||OpenCVModules-release.cmake
||OpenCVModules.cmake
|lib/opencv/debug
||OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
||OpenCVConfig.cmake
||OpenCVModules-debug.cmake
||OpenCVModules.cmake
```

i first checked these files for differences and the only file that's different are the `OpenCVModules-<BUILD_TYPE>.cmake` files. so i moved the files into `lib/opencv/cmake` so it looked like this:

```
|lib/opencv/cmake
||OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
||OpenCVConfig.cmake
||OpenCVModules-debug.cmake
||OpenCVModules-release.cmake
||OpenCVModules.cmake
```

I did this because in the `OpenCVModules.cmake` i found this line:

```
file(glob CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/OpenCVModules-*.cmake")
```

which searches the specific Modules files.
after this i changed the find_package directive to:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/opencv/cmake")
```

and now it works.